# Using a AIC or LRT for a GLM and LMM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, aic, likelihood-ratio

I am trying to compare 2 models (a GLMER with a random effect and a GLM with the random effect removed). However, I was told you can't use an AIC for GLM's but I thought you could!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what models you are working on, however I don't think this is strictly necessary for a general answer. How are you estimating the GLM? Are you using Maximum likelihood? If so, why you should not use Akaike's (same story for LR test)? A couple of links pointing to this may be of some help [link 1](http://users.monash.edu/~dschmidt/ModelSectionTutorial1_SchmidtMakalic_2008.pdf)  [link 2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74676-the-akaike-s-information-criteria-value-calculation)

**Edited:**
If your aim is to test the joint significance of the two independent variables (i.e. to test whether your model as a whole is significant or not), then I would use a Wald test [link wald](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/wald-test/) or a LR test where you restrict both the variables to be 0 and compare the restricted model to the model with both variablkes left inside. If instead your ambition is to define whether to use 1 or 2 variables for the model and which variables then use a specification crierion or info criteria (different IC may give different answers as they impose a different penalty function on the number of parameters Akaike's [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), Bayesian [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), Hannan-Quinn [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannan%E2%80%93Quinn_information_criterion))

Comment: My model is looking at how 2 categorical variables affected a count variable (e.g. number of days). e.g. x~y*z. However, when I run my AIC and LRT on the model they give contrasting results as to what model is best. My overall aim of the model is to determine if these 2 categorical variables significantly impact the count variable. My models are nested too

Comment: @user255144 Edited my answer in light of your comment